# JMapper complex/ Reference Object mapping

Tags: mapping

I'm also looking for Mapping reference Object property using **JMapper**. For example.

```
 class Person {   int id;   Address addr; }

 class Address {String city;}
```

I want to map 'city' from Address class to my Desitnation class instead of mapping 'addr' property to Address type.

```
class Destination {
    @JMap int id; 

    @JMap 
    Sting city; 
}
```

I used **@JMap("city") or @JMap("addr.city")**, but nothing work. Even I don't see any documentation regarding that. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested Mapping is available with the convention `${field.field}`.

For more information visit the [wiki page](https://github.com/jmapper-framework/jmapper-core/wiki/Nested-Mapping).